# MySQL - Slow Query when kept a View

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I have a simple join between 2 tables. Something like

```
select a.id, SUM(b.qty) from a inner join b on a.id=b.id
where a.id=12345
group by a.id
```

It runs normal as a query. But when I keep the query

```
select a.id, SUM(b.qty) from a inner join b on a.id=b.id
group by a.id
```

in a view called `view_ab`, the view takes enormous amount of time when i run the following query on the view.

```
select * from view_ab where id = 12345
```

Both these tables are large tables. Unable to figure out the reason for such a drop in performance. Please help resolve this performance issue

EDIT:
This is the view SQL

```
CREATE VIEW view_ab AS SELECT 
r.drid            AS drid,
SUM(s.return_qty) AS return_qty
FROM tbl_deliveryroute r INNER JOIN tbl_deliveryroute_sku s ON r.drid = 
s.drid GROUP BY r.drid;
```

This is the query

```
SELECT 
r.drid            AS drid,
SUM(s.return_qty) AS return_qty
FROM tbl_deliveryroute r INNER JOIN tbl_deliveryroute_sku s ON r.drid = 
s.drid WHERE r.drid=12718651
GROUP BY r.drid;
```

This is the query on the VIEW

```
SELECT * FROM view_ab WHERE drid=12718651;
```

Execution plan of the view

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM view_ab WHERE drid=12718651;
```

id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra

1
PRIMARY

(NULL)
ref


4
const
10
100.00
(NULL)

2
DERIVED
s
(NULL)
ALL
idx_tbl_deliverroute_sku_drid
(NULL)
(NULL)
(NULL)
15060913
100.00
USING TEMPORARY; USING filesort

2
DERIVED
r
(NULL)
eq_ref
PRIMARY,FK_tbl_deliveryroute_1
PRIMARY
4
humdemotest.s.drid
1
100.00
USING INDEX

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED  SELECT 
r.drid            AS drid,
SUM(s.return_qty) AS return_qty
FROM tbl_deliveryroute r INNER JOIN tbl_deliveryroute_sku s ON r.drid = 
s.drid WHERE r.drid=12718651
GROUP BY r.drid;
```

id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra

1
SIMPLE
r
(NULL)
const
PRIMARY
PRIMARY
4
const
1
100.00
USING INDEX

1
SIMPLE
s
(NULL)
ref
idx_tbl_deliverroute_sku_drid
idx_tbl_deliverroute_sku_drid
4
const
22
100.00
(NULL)

Comment: Please examine the execution plans of both queries by prepending `EXPLAIN` to each of them. Note that for the former MySQL may be doing *filtering* first then *grouping*, and for the latter vice-versa which kind of explains the issue. (If this is the case, you could stick to a stored procedure instead.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. The PLAN for each of these statements is different. Also, we have recently setup a staging environment of our production environment. This view is used extensively. Moving to a stored procedure means much work

Comment: The same view works well in the production environment. The issue with the view is experienced in the staging environment only.

Comment: Posting an `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` result of the query (possibly censoring sensitive information) would be helpful. Also, it might be worth checking if both schemas for staging and production environment are identical, especially the KEY / INDEX part.

Comment: I suggest you to edit your question and put results there instead (along with everything else you elaborated on in your comments). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you dispense with the view. It offers no benefit that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

From what I am seeing, you don't even need a join since you are dealing with a join on the same key column from A-B, the key already exists in table B, just query group by that.  Also, I would have an index on your DeliveryRoute_SKU on its route ID column

```
SELECT 
      s.drid,
      sum( s.return_qty ) Return_Qty
   from
      tbl_DeliveryRoute_Sku s
   where
      s.drID = 12718651
   group by
      s.drID;
```

Since you are only doing the key and the sum, you don't even NEED the other table.  Now if you needed other columns from the first table OTHER THAN the key, then yes, you would need the join.  You could even simplify a step further since you are only querying a single key ID

```
SELECT 
      sum( s.return_qty ) Return_Qty
   from
      tbl_DeliveryRoute_Sku s
   where
      s.drID = 12718651;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the view is slow is simple.  You are executing:

```
SELECT *
FROM view_ab
WHERE drid = 12718651;
```

What you want to execute is:

```
select a.id, SUM(b.qty)
from a inner join
     b
     on a.id = b.id
where a.id = 12345
group by a.id;
```

What is actually being executed is:

```
select ab.*
from (select a.id, SUM(b.qty)
      from a inner join
           b
           on a.id = b.id
      group by a.id
     ) ab
where ab.id = 12345;
```

That is, the entire aggregation is performed first.  *Then* the `where` is applied.  What you want is for the predicate to be pushed up (MySQL calls this merging).  You can review the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html) on this subject.

One solution would seem to be rephrasing the query as a correlated subquery:

```
select a.id,
       (select sum(b.qty) from b where b.id = a.id) as qty
from a 
where a.id = 12345;
```

Alas, subqueries in the `select` have the same effect, so this doesn't work.

I don't know of a solution using a view.  You can avoid using views for this.  The ultimate solution would be to implement a trigger to store the summarized results in another table -- effectively materializing the view.